# Why wasn't the synchronous action executed until the asynchronous action completed?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-ajax, comet

I'm implementing Comet in ASP.NET MVC.  I used a timer to keep an async request in the server.  The async request will complete when the timer elapses after 1 minute and sends a response to the client (to avoid 404 error) and then reconnects to Async Controller.

I also want to execute some synchronous actions while the async request was holding, but the problem is:

- **When an async action was executed and hold by using timer, the sync action wasn't called until the async action (Comet long-live request) completed**.

I did the test with Firefox 3.6 many times, but the result is always the same; it is so strange. Do you know why?

I have a sub-question:

- **To implement Comet, using a timer (response after some minutes elapsed) or thread (response after several time sleeping thread) to hold async request; which is better?**

Comment: Show me the money... er... source code.

Comment: I will show some source for u

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer for my problems.
First,the reason why **Sync action wasn't executed while Async action holding** because **session request block mechanic**, Asp.net session block request so that all requests will be process one by one even you use concurrent request with Ajax Async Call. And the solution is disable session on controller you want to hold long-live request. Here is detail explanation: https://blogs.msdn.com/b/rickandy/archive/2009/12/17/session-less-mvc-controller.aspx 
The second, when perform holding long-live request,using timer and thread sleeping are NOT different, because Asp.net thread pool will essentially create new thread to track time elapsed and call back to your timer elapsed event. It will decrease number of threads to serve request in thread pool because it born new thread to track timer event.